# Kubernetes LoadBalancer Service not loadbalancing requests

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, skaffold

I have a simple microservice setup running in a minikube cluster. It is inspired by [this example.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo)
My setup includes a simple `router` microservice that contains a golang webserver. What I want to test now is the loadbalancing when there is more then one pod. But there seems to be no load-balancing whatsoever.

The kubernetes file for the microservices looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: router
  labels:
    app: router
    tier: router
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: router
        tier: router
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: {myregistry}/router
        name: router
        resources: {}
        ports:
          - name: target-port
            containerPort: 8082
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "8082"
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: router
  labels:
    app: router
    tier: router
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: router
    tier: router
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    name: http
    targetPort: target-port
```

The skaffold config looks like this:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta2
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: {myregistry}/router
    context: src/router/bin
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
  local:
    push: false
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - ./kubernetes/**.yaml
```

Kubernetes correctly deploys two pods. The output of `kubectl get pods` looks like this:

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
router-7f75f6f9df-c8mgp        1/1     Running   0          14m
router-7f75f6f9df-k248m        1/1     Running   0          14m
```

From the `skaffold dev` log output I can see that every request is routed to the `router-7f75f6f9df-c8mgp` pod. Even with different browsers all requests end up at the exact same pod.

When I delete this pod there is even a slight downtime of the router microservice even though there is another pod running.

What could be the problem of this behavior?

Comment: From my understanding, services of type LoadBalancer are only supported if you are using a  cloud provider as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). Are you sure your Service is working correctly? What's the output of `kubectl get service router`?

Comment: Yes it does not seem to work correctly @AlassaneNdiaye. The external IP is forever pending but i thought it would still work through port forwarding. But I get it now that it is not meant for that use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

minikube doesn't 'properly' support the LoadBalancer service type. It used to be commonplace to just use the NodePort or externalIP service type instead, however the official [hello-minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) sample now states:

> On cloud providers that support load balancers, an external IP address
>   would be provisioned to access the Service. On Minikube, the
>   LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the minikube
>   service command

So effectively you should be able to use your minikube LoadBalancer service with: `minikube service router`

However there is a neat solution that was developed for bare-metal kubernetes clusters called **metallb** that may be able to help you test this in a better way on minikube.

You can install and configure it on minikube. E.g.

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.1/manifests/metallb.yaml`

Here are some blog posts where others have explained the setup and use of metallb with minikube for LoadBalancer support:

[Blog Post 1](https://medium.com/@emirmujic/istio-and-metallb-on-minikube-242281b1134b)
[Blog Post 2](https://ervikrant06.github.io/kubernetes/metallb-LB-on-minikube/)

Here are the [official docs](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

Hope that helps!